# I created a Web + Apps property should I migrate to gtag.js?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I created a Web + Apps property but it seems like there is no way to send events to it through analytics.js and I`m not able to find the tracking number for the new property.
should I migrate to gtag.js?

Answer (score 0):

i think below post is helpful to solve your problems.

https://www.kristaseiden.com/step-by-step-setting-up-an-app-web-config-tag-in-gtm/

This posts saids that just use an App+web config tag from your GTM to collecting data from your websites. So migration doesn't seem necessary.

As you read the post, you'll realize that this new property provides 'measurement ID' instead of 'tracking id'(seems to be synonymous word). when you create web 'stream' from new property, you can easily get your measurement id. just use this when you create new config tag from GTM.

[measurement id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oITJ.png)